# Is it possible to insert value for required field without value in dataloader?

Tags: data-loader

I have small clarification I need to upload excel file. I need to upload required field column without any value  upload via data loader. Is it possible?
Please can any one help me out for this issue

Comment: if the field is required on the object you have to populate it. If it is required on the object why would you want to upload null values as it defeats the purpose of a required field.

Comment: Your question and description saying two different things. If field is defined as required at field level value is always required in that field. But if it is defined at page layout you can skip that field

Comment: @Eric thanks for your reply I have uploaded dummy record and testing purpose. Is it possible to upload  without values for require field.

Comment: @Himanshu I agree your point. I need to know for testing purpose..

Comment: Ok, you got your answer now? I an Eric saying same thing.

Comment: if you are just updating records that already exist then you do not have to include the required column since it is already populated